# Group By IP class

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I save log access in MongoDB like

```
{
   "Host": "www.foo.com"
   "CustomField":"X-FORWARDED-FROM 10.10.10.10"
},{
   "Host": "www.foo.com"
   "CustomField":"X-FORWARDED-FROM 10.20.10.192"
},{
   "Host": "www.foo.com"
   "CustomField":"X-FORWARDED-FROM 10.10.20.159"
},{
   "Host": "www.foo.com"
   "CustomField":"X-FORWARDED-FROM 10.10.10.150"
}
```

I want to query with an output for summary ip access like

```
{
   "_id":"10.10.10.0", "count":2,
   "_id":"10.10.20.0", "count":1,
   "_id":"10.20.10.0", "count":1,
}
```

How do I go about this?

Comment: is `X-FORWARDED-FROM` fixed for every `CustomField` ?

Comment: X-FORWARDED-FROM is fixed.

Comment: can try my answer

Comment: Thank you. I try your solution. I work but it is isn't group IP class. please see my comment.

Answer (score 1):

If we make assumption that the collection name is `ips` and the `"CustomField"` property is always being represented as `"X-FORWARDED-FROM THE_IP_ADDRESS"`, then the following query aggregation gives the desired result:

```
db.ips.aggregate([{
    $project:{
        _id:{
            $substr:["$CustomField", 17, -1]
        }
    },
},{
    $project: {
      ip: {$split:["$_id", "."]}
    },
},{
    $project: {
      ip: {$slice:["$ip", 3]}
    },
}, {
    $project: {
      ip: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$ip",
          initialValue: "",
          in: { $concat : ["$$value", "$$this", "."] }
        }
      }
    }
}, {
    $group:{
        _id: "$ip", count:{$sum:1}
    }
}, {
    $project: {
      _id:{$concat:["$_id", "0"]},
      count: 1
    }
}])
```

It does the following aggregation:

1. Takes IP address from the string
2. Splits the string into arrays of 4 parts of IP address
3. Removes the last part from the array
4. Concatenates array elements into a string
5. Groups them by IP address
6. Finally concatenates "0" to the `_id` field as a last part of IP address

Comment: Thank you. your solution is work. but result isn't group by IP class. It is 
`{
   "_id":"10.10.10.10", "count":1,
   "_id":"10.20.10.192", "count":1,
   "_id":"10.10.20.159", "count":1,
   "_id":"10.10.10.150", "count":1,
}`

Comment: At first I've got wrong your question, because it was little bit confusing related to the last part of the IP address. However I've updated my answer, now it gives  the output you want.

Answer (score 0):

If **X-FORWARDED-FROM** string is fixed for every `CustomField` then can solve by using [$substr](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/substr/).

```
db.CollectionName.aggregate([
    {$group:{
        _id:"$CustomField",
        count:{$sum:1}
        }
    },
    {$project:{
        _id: { $substr: [ "$_id", 17, -1] },
        count:1
        }
    }
])
```

where **17** means start from. that's the length of *X-FORWARDED-FROM* string

**Updated:**

```
db.CollectionName.aggregate([
    {$project:{
        ip: {$concat: [{ $substr: [ "$CustomField", 17,8] },'.0']}
        }
    },
    {$group:{
        _id:"$ip",
        count:{$sum:1}
        }
    }
])
```

for **MongoDB 3.4** can use

```
db.CollectionName..aggregate([
    {$project:{
        ip:{ $split: [ { $substr: [ "$CustomField", 17,-1] }, "." ] }//ip: ["10","10","10","192"]
       }
    },
    {$project:{
        ip:{ $concat: [ 
            { $arrayElemAt: [ "$ip", 0 ] },
            " . ", 
            { $arrayElemAt: [ "$ip", 1 ] },
            ".",
            { $arrayElemAt: [ "$ip", 2 ] },
            ".0"
            ] }
       },
    },
    {$group:{
        _id:"$ip",
        count:{$sum:1}
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: Thank you. your solution is work. but result isn't group by IP class. It is 
`{
   "_id":"10.10.10.10", "count":1,
   "_id":"10.20.10.192", "count":1,
   "_id":"10.10.20.159", "count":1,
   "_id":"10.10.10.150", "count":1,
}`

Comment: what do you mean by ip class  first three part ? @WatcharaKangkun

Comment: IP  class is mean first three part of ip address like 

10.10.10.10 and 10.10.10.150 is same ip class